# My elastic search is not showing any data using elastic-agent

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Surprisingly my elastic version 7.15 with basic license have installed the fleet server and then configured windows-policy with elastic-endpoint and windows integration. Have enabled all the rules; however I am not seeing any logs security app. I am specifically using feet server to enroll agents and collecting windows logs.
Have added windows agent on my Domain controller as well as ADC but still not seeing any logs.

Any clue why? Plus I am seeing below logs in kibana.log consistently.

```
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2021-10-07T22:43:49+05:30","tags":["info","plugins","securitySolution"],"pid":1102,"message":"[+] Finished indexing 0  signals searched between date ranges [\n  {\n    \"to\": \"2021-10-07T17:13:49.667Z\",\n    \"from\": \"2021-10-07T17:04:49.667Z\",\n    \"maxSignals\": 100\n  }\n] name: \"SystemKey Access via Command Line\" id: \"c2c1fbc1-229f-11ec-803f-17c1b2345c64\" rule id: \"d75991f2-b989-419d-b797-ac1e54ec2d61\" signals index: \".siem-signals-default\""}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2021-10-07T22:43:49+05:30","tags":["error","plugins","securitySolution"],"pid":1102,"message":"An error occurred during rule execution: message: \"index_not_found_exception: [verification_exception] Reason: Found 1 problem\nline -1:-1: Unknown index [*,-*]\" name: \"Clearing Windows Event Logs\" id: \"c2c1fbd5-229f-11ec-803f-17c1b2345c64\" rule id: \"d331bbe2-6db4-4941-80a5-8270db72eb61\" signals index: \".siem-signals-default\""}
 {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2021-10-07T23:21:53+05:30","tags":["error","plugins","securitySolution"],"pid":10188,"message":"An error occurred during rule execution: message: \"index_not_found_exception: [verification_exception] Reason: Found 1 problem\nline -1:-1: Unknown index [*,-*]\" name: \"Suspicious PrintSpooler Service Executable File Creation\" id: \"c2c2710c-229f-11ec-803f-17c1b2345c64\" rule id: \"5bb4a95d-5a08-48eb-80db-4c3a63ec78a8\" signals index: \".siem-signals-default\""}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2021-10-07T23:21:53+05:30","tags":["error","plugins","securitySolution"],"pid":10188,"message":"An error occurred during rule execution: message: \"index_not_found_exception: [verification_exception] Reason: Found 1 problem\nline -1:-1: Unknown index [*,-*]\" name: \"Unusual File Creation - Alternate Data Stream\" id: \"c2c41eb3-229f-11ec-803f-17c1b2345c64\" rule id: \"71bccb61-e19b-452f-b104-79a60e546a95\" signals index: \".siem-signals-default\""}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2021-10-07T23:21:53+05:30","tags":["error","plugins","securitySolution"],"pid":10188,"message":"An error occurred during rule execution: message: \"index_not_found_exception: [verification_exception] Reason: Found 1 problem\nline -1:-1: Unknown index [*,-*]\" name: \"Persistence via WMI Standard Registry Provider\" id: \"c2c445ba-229f-11ec-803f-17c1b2345c64\" rule id: \"70d12c9c-0dbd-4a1a-bc44-1467502c9cf6\" signals index: \".siem-signals-default\""}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2021-10-07T23:21:53+05:30","tags":["error","plugins","securitySolution"],"pid":10188,"message":"An error occurred during rule execution: message: \"index_not_found_exception: [verification_exception] Reason: Found 1 problem\nline -1:-1: Unknown index [*,-*]\" name: \"Microsoft Exchange Worker Spawning Suspicious Processes\" id: \"c2c445b7-229f-11ec-803f-17c1b2345c64\" rule id: \"f81ee52c-297e-46d9-9205-07e66931df26\" signals index: \".siem-signals-default\""}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2021-10-07T23:21:53+05:30","tags":["error","plugins","securitySolution"],"pid":10188,"message":"An error occurred during rule execution: message: \"index_not_found_exception: [verification_exception] Reason: Found 1 problem\nline -1:-1: Unknown index [*,-*]\" name: \"Persistence via Microsoft Outlook VBA\" id: \"c2c3345f-229f-11ec-803f-17c1b2345c64\" rule id: \"397945f3-d39a-4e6f-8bcb-9656c2031438\" signals index: \".siem-signals-default\""}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2021-10-07T23:21:53+05:30","tags":["error","plugins","securitySolution"],"pid":10188,"message":"An error occurred during rule execution: message: \"index_not_found_exception: [verification_exception] Reason: Found 1 problem\nline -1:-1: Unknown index [*,-*]\" name: \"Persistence via KDE AutoStart Script or Desktop File Modification\" id: \"c2c3f7a8-229f-11ec-803f-17c1b2345c64\" rule id: \"e3e904b3-0a8e-4e68-86a8-977a163e21d3\" signals index: \".siem-signals-default\""}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2021-10-07T23:21:53+05:30","tags":["error","plugins","securitySolution"],"pid":10188,"message":"An error occurred during rule execution: message: \"index_not_found_exception: [verification_exception] Reason: Found 1 problem\nline -1:-1: Unknown index [*,-*]\" name: \"Installation of Security Support Provider\" id: \"c2c3344f-229f-11ec-803f-17c1b2345c64\" rule id: \"e86da94d-e54b-4fb5-b96c-cecff87e8787\" signals index: \".siem-signals-default\""}
```